# get lower triangular matrix with for loop without built in function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I need to create a lower triangular matrix out of a specified matrix, without using the lower.try function, specifically with nested for loops.
I have gotten this far...

```
d <- 6
m <- matrix(1:(d*d), d, d)
for(i in 2:nrow(m)) {
  for (j in 1:col(m)) {
    #...skipped code
  }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean *"get lower triangular matrix"*? If your intended output is exactly the same as `lower.tri`, then you need to create an empty matrix first. If your intended output is different, perhaps a vector of the values of a matrix's lower triangle, then it will be a vector. Please be specific on what your intended output is for this specific 6x6 matrix. And this sounds like homework, is that right? It's fine if it is, but it's nice etiquette to be honest about that.

Comment: I mean I need to replace all values below the diagonal with zeros.I am sorry I am new to coding and this is my first time posting a coding question, therefore was unaware of the etiquette. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: If `i` is your row and `j` is your column, then you want to replace the value when `i > j`, right? That should mark where you are *below the diagonal*. With that, create an `if` statement that checks for that and, if true, assigns 0 to `m[i,j]`. (Even forgetting that we have `lower.tri` already made, there are far better/faster ways to do this, but I understand you must use two `for` loops.)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to implement a gaussian elimination's steps but instead of eliminating the i'th column elements in the i'th step, you should try to eliminate the last elements.

```
mymat <- matrix(sample(x = c(1:10),replace = T,size = 25), ncol = 5, nrow = 5, byrow = T)  

#iterating from the last row, to the first
for(j in nrow(mymat):1){
  if(j>1){
    #iterating from first, to the one before the current
    for(i in 1:(j-1)){
      #subtract the two rows but with the corresponding multiplier to eliminate the column's variables
      multiplier <- mymat[i,j]/mymat[j,j] 
      mymat[i,] <- mymat[i,]-multiplier*mymat[j,]
    }
  }
  #to get 1s in the diagonal line
  mymat[j,] <- mymat[j,]/mymat[j,j]
}
```

If you don't want to get 1s in the diagonal:

```
for(j in nrow(mymat):1){
  if(j>1){
    for(i in 1:(j-1)){
      multiplier <- mymat[i,j]/mymat[j,j] 
      mymat[i,] <- mymat[i,]-multiplier*mymat[j,]
    }
  }
  mymat[j,] <- mymat[j,]/mymat[j,j]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the answer with the following code, but I wish I could get the same output without the if statement

```
d <- 6
m <- matrix(1:(d*d), d, d)
for(i in 2:nrow(m)) {
for (j in 1:ncol(m)) {
    if (m[i,j] < diag(m)[i]) {
    m[i,j] <-0
    }
  } 
} m

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    7   13   19   25   31
[2,]    0    8   14   20   26   32
[3,]    0    0   15   21   27   33
[4,]    0    0    0   22   28   34
[5,]    0    0    0    0   29   35
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0   36
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not add a comment yet, I'm going to post this as another answer. You can do the following, without the if statement:

```
d <- 6
m <- matrix(1:(d*d), d, d)
for(i in c(2:dim(m)[1])) # from 2 to the number of rows
  for(j in c(1:(i-1)))   # from 1 to the number of the current iteration - 1
    m[i,j] <- 0

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    7   13   19   25   31
[2,]    0    8   14   20   26   32
[3,]    0    0   15   21   27   33
[4,]    0    0    0   22   28   34
[5,]    0    0    0    0   29   35
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0   36
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- 6
m <- matrix(1:(d*d), d, d)

for (j in 1:(d-1)) {
  for (i in (j+1):d) {
    m[i,j] = 0
  }
}
```

Val A's answer gave me some insight. I just fix the minor error. Now you do not need if statement to do the work.